# Android Shared Preferences don't Save Properly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to use Android Shared Preferences to save certain app values
Here is the code of my onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean firstLaunch = preferences.getBoolean("firstlaunch", true);

    System.out.println("FIRST LAUNCH? " + firstLaunch);

    if(firstLaunch == true){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("language", "en");
        editor.putInt("theme", R.style.Default);
        editor.putBoolean("firstLaunch", false);
        editor.commit();
        System.out.println("FIRST LAUNCH:" + preferences.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true));
    }
```

When I restart the app, firstLaunch is still true? Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a case issue.
`firstlaunch` vs `firstLaunch`

To avoid this kind of problem you should use a static member.

```
private static final String KEY_PREFS_NAME = "myPrefs";
private static final String KEY_FIRST_LAUNCH = "firstLaunch";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean firstLaunch = preferences.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_LAUNCH, true);

System.out.println("FIRST LAUNCH? " + firstLaunch);

if(firstLaunch == true){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("language", "en");
    editor.putInt("theme", R.style.Default);
    editor.putBoolean(KEY_FIRST_LAUNCH, false);
    editor.commit();
    System.out.println("FIRST LAUNCH:" + preferences.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_LAUNCH, true));
}
```

Comment: Wow to think that was the error! Thanks i'll do this in the future to avoid this type of error

Answer (score 3):

Your key value is not spelled properly when you retrieve it so you always get `true` change and you commit to the wrong key.

Change

```
 boolean firstLaunch = preferences.getBoolean("firstlaunch", true);
```

to

```
 boolean firstLaunch = preferences.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true);
```